# How to into data into a MySQL using JPA and @Query named Parameters

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am getting the following error:

```
Using named parameters for method public static void com.htd.repository.MaterialRepository.uploadMaterialData(java.lang.String,java.math.BigDecimal,java.lang.String,java.math.BigDecimal,java.math.BigDecimal) but parameter 'material_number' not found in annotated query 'INSERT INTO hillcresttooldie VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)'!
```

I read the documention at:
http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.4.3.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html but I am still having issues. I was under the impression JPA created queries for us. I am used to writing out the queries until I cam across this awesome piece of technology.

```
public interface MaterialRepository extends JpaRepository<Material,Long> {

    @Query("INSERT INTO hillcresttooldie VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)")
    static void uploadMaterialData(String material_number,BigDecimal material_thickness,String material_size,BigDecimal lb_per_sheet,BigDecimal dollar_per_lb) {


    }
}
```

Trying to use the query in the MaterialResource.java file

```
//puts materials into map and the key is the material number
                materialMap.put(materialValue, material);

                MaterialRepository.uploadMaterialData(material.getMaterial_number(), material.getMaterial_thickness(),
                        material.getMaterial_size(), material.getLb_per_sheet(), material.getDollar_per_lb());
```

Comment: I don't get what you are trying. You use JPA but are writing native queries yourself? Why? Just save the `Material` instance using the default `save` method on the `JpaRepository`? Seems like you need to catch up on how JPA works.

Comment: @M.Deinum I am simply reading the documentation at http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.4.3.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html and doing my best to get this done. I know there has to be a better way to do this. I am just not there at the moment.

Comment: Understand JPA first before using technologies making it easier to use JPA. You are mixing and confusing things. As stated, ditch the method and just call `save`.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to

```
@Query("INSERT INTO hillcresttooldie (material_number,material_thickness,material_size,lb_per_sheet,dollar_per_lb) VALUES (:number, :thickness, :size, :lbPerSheet, :dollarPerLb)")
void uploadMaterialData(String number, BigDecimal thickness, String size, BigDecimal lbPerSheet, BigDecimal dollarPerLb)
```

Comment: I did that and got 
*`expecting OPEN, found 'VALUES' near line 1, column 30 [INSERT INTO hillcresttooldie VALUES (:material_number, :material_thickness,:material_size,:lb_per_sheet,:dollar_per_lb)]`

Comment: Oups, sorry, bad copy paste. Fixed now. That said, why the hell are you using insert queries with JPA. Just create an instance of your entity, and call entityManager.persist()

Comment: @ JB Nizet This my first time doing this and I am trying to figure it out. You happen to know a good place that gives me some good examples on how to do this? I would like to do it correctly and not create extra work for myself if there is a better way.

Comment: I've learnt JPA/Hibernate a looong time ago. But pick a JPA tutorial at Oracle, and learn JPA. You're missing fundamentals.

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
public interface MaterialRepository extends JpaRepository<Material,Long> {

@Modifying
@Query(nativeQuery = true,"INSERT INTO hillcresttooldie(material_number,material_thickness,material_size,lb_per_sheet,dollar_per_lb) VALUES (?1,?2,?3,?4,?5)")
static void uploadMaterialData(String material_number,BigDecimal material_thickness,String material_size,BigDecimal lb_per_sheet,BigDecimal dollar_per_lb) {


}
```

}

```
public interface MaterialRepository extends JpaRepository<Material,Long> {

@Query("INSERT INTO hillcresttooldie(material_number) VALUES (:material_number)") //....
static void uploadMaterialData(@Param("material_number") String material_number) {


}
```

}

Comment: I tried both of your suggestions and got the following error:

`expecting OPEN, found 'VALUES' near line 1, column 30 [INSERT INTO hillcresttooldie VALUES (:material_number), (:material_thickness),(:material_size),(:lb_per_sheet),(:dollar_per_lb))]`

Comment: I just added `@Modifying @Query("INSERT INTO hillcresttooldie...` and got the same error.

Comment: remove parentheses [INSERT INTO hillcresttooldie VALUES (:material_number, :material_thickness,:material_size,:lb_per_sheet,:dollar_per_lb)]

Comment: I cannot do that because I get the follow error:

`INTO cannot be resolved to a type`